# prepare two model the same time in ember route

Tags: ember.js, model, promise

I need 2 model working together to show products at website.
I have a ProductController so product model is set properly, as i need option to show the products also, i need prepare it somewhere(means resolve the promise before controller run),
i think the setupController is the right place so i set 'option' property there, like below:

```
var Product = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  price: DS.attr('number'),
  img: DS.attr('array')
});

var Option = DS.Model.extend({
  productId: DS.attr('number'),
  drawType: DS.attr('string'),
  background: DS.attr('string'),
  positionX: DS.attr('number'),
  positionY: DS.attr('number')
});

 App.ProductRoute =  Ember.Route.extend({
   setupController: function(controller, model) {
    controller.set('model', model);
    // i want to prepare option well so controller can get real data 
    // instead of a promise 
    this.store.find('option', 0).then(function(data){
      controller.set('option', data);
    });
  })
})

App.ProductController =  Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  init: function(){
    this._super();
    console.log('can i get option in init?:', this.get('option'));
  }
})
```

but it not work as i expected, the output in productController init is undefined. could anyone help, where am i wrong? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An idea would be to use the [afterModel hook](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/asynchronous-routing/#toc_code-aftermodel-code) to fetch your option object and set it as an attribute on the route. Then in setupController you can set that object on the controller as well.

```
App.ProductRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  option: null,

  afterModel: function() {
    var _this = this;
    return this.store.find('option', 0).then(function(data) {
      _this.set('option', data);
    });
  },

  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    controller.set('model', model);
    controller.set('option', this.get('option'));
  }
});
```

However, I don't think you will have access to the option object (or even the model) in the init() function of the controller, since setupController() is called after init().

Side note - you may want to replace the field `productId: DS.attr('number')` in Option with `product: DS.belongsTo('product')`.

Comment: thank you. this is my first ember project, the main answer as well as the 2 notes are very helpful. "setupController() is called after init()", i thought all methods in route is invoked before controller.

Comment: Well setupController receives a controller as argument - so the controller must exist before setupController is called.